# DataTier Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have Visual studio project about dataTier application, I prepared a project and in the same solution I have windows from application project.

I want to add as a reference dataTier project to Windows from project.
How can I do it?

Data tier Project in visual studio has no .exe or .dll file so I can not add it as a reference.

Comment: place the dll on the bin directory of your project

Answer (score 0):

The Data tier Project will produce a .exe or .dll file if it compiles successfully on build. Looking in the Project Folder, you'll usually find it in the \bin\Debug or bin\Release subfolder (depending on which build configuration you've used).

But usually you don't want to add a reference in this way. If you right-click on a Project name in Visual Studio, you'll be presented with a menu which has an 'Add Reference' menu item. Click on this, then choose 'Projects' as the type of reference you want to add. You should see all other Projects which are included in the Visual Studio Solution. Just choose the one you want to reference and that's it.

**EDIT:** Ah, I realise now you're probably talking about the SQL Server Data Tier project type, which contains SQL scripts rather than compiled code so therefore can't be referenced by a C# project.

So, what are you actually trying to achieve here?